# Battery life is inconsistent

Tags: battery

If I charge my battery above 95%
Ubuntu shows 12 hour battery life.
If I charge to 92% it shows 3 hour battery life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on ubuntu 16.04 but other version should have similar tools.

Launch "Power statistics" app.
From the list on the left choose "Laptop battery" then choose "Statistics". There, from the drop-down menu for "graph type" you can select "charge / discharge accuracy". Mine shows a "Prediction accuracy vs cell charge" graph and clearly the prediction accuracy drops significantly when the cell charge exceeds 90 percent. Of course yours will be different than mine but the very fact that these graphs exist signals that this kind of a problem is common. The predictions are also bad when the cell charge is below 10 percent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh so this is just a bug in ubuntu, thank you

Comment: No problem. No not really, I mean I don't think there is a mistake in the code but rather, predicting remaining discharge time of a battery is hard, there is on going research about it.